# Active cell as input to formula

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I was wondering if I can use the active cell, by that I mean the cell that is "highlighted" at a given time with the square border after there was a mouse click there, as an argument in a function.

For example, I have created a table with weighted averages with 3 weights: w1 is given in the column headers (kindly see the file below), w2 in the row headers, and w3 which complements w1 and w2 to 1.

What I'd like to do is have cells outside the table show the weights the average got when a cell in the table is selected.

For example:
Screenshot: http://imgur.com/emmBH5S/

file can be found here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_7-00fdslR7Tm11ODRVS296ckk/

Here we see the cell K12 is active,
and for K12 w1=0.2, w2=0.15, and so, the cells in the weights tables above (rows 3-4) get the appropriate values according to the weights in the active cell.
(of course I manually created this one for illustration purposes)

Is there a way to do that? Preferably without VBA if possible 
Couldn't find anything very useful...

Thanks in advance!
A

Comment: the imgur upload is lost to time.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You don't need VBA (although you may prefer it).

```
W1: =INDEX($F$8:$AA$29,1,MAX(COLUMN(INDIRECT(CELL("address")))-(COLUMN(F8)-1),1))
W2: =INDEX($F$8:$AA$29,MAX(ROW(INDIRECT(CELL("address")))-(ROW(F8)-1),1),1)
W3: =J4-(G4+H4)
```

The `CELL` function with the `address` argument returns the address for whichever cell is active. I use `INDIRECT` to convert that address (just a string) to a cell reference. Then I use

```
=INDEX(Range, 1, Column of Reference)
```

to get the w1 value - the value in the first row and the same column as the active cell. The formula doesn't care what cell you make active, so I stuck a `MAX` in there so it would return a zero if you're out of the range.

Note that simply selecting a cell won't trigger the change. Once you select a cell, press F9 to calculate the sheet to get the proper results.

Comment: this is AWESOME. Beautiful. Thank you.
Q: I went to an empty cell and wrote 'code'=CELL("address")'code'. I got the location of the active cell. Then in another empty cell, I wrote 'code'=indirect(cell("address"))'code' and the weird thing is that it would return the value in the active cell of anything in the range of values in the sample file (the one you hedged with your formulae) G9:AA29 even without me defining it anywhere! I used the bare bone formulae w/o limiting to a range. Only when I hit F9 it would evaluate that active cell if it's outside of that range. Strange, no?

Comment: Do you still have the SelectionChange code? Firing that code would cause a recalc because it writes to the sheet. If you get rid of the code, you won't see that behavior. Also, I should have noted that the results become very unreliable when you're on a different sheet.

Answer (score 5):

You need to use VBA. Following your example place this code in your Sheet object

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Row > 8 And Target.Column > 6 Then
        Range("G4").Value = Cells(8, Target.Column).Value
        Range("H4").Value = Cells(Target.Row, 6).Value
        Range("L4").Value = Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column).Value
    End If
End Sub
```

Cell `L4` shows your selected cell value which can be used in other formulas.

**EDIT**

To place your code you go to VBA window and double click on the Sheet object where you have your data. (Marked with an arrow in the picture)
Then paste yout code.
[image: Code in Worksheet object]

Comment: thanks... but how do i include the result in a formula? Can you please create a formula which takes the value of the active cell as input?

Comment: As per my edit, the result is shown in cell L4. Then you can create a formula which makes reference to that cell L4.

Comment: Nothing happens when I click on a cell. I must be missing something simple. Sorry for being a pain :(