# Clicking on a cell and a singular, different cell is highlighted in the active row

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting, gantt-chart

My excel sheet/ gantt chart covers a yearly plan, making the amount of columns quite large. Is there a way to click on a cell in the "item_in_plan" bars and highlight the "task" cell in that same row? Attached is a screenshot of the chart to pain a better picture.

For example,

If I were to click on X24, C24 would ideally be highlighted.

[image: screenshot]

I saw a few videos on how to highlight the whole row, but I'm just wanting a certain cell. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Consider using VBA, specifically the `Worksheet_SelectionChange` event handler.

Comment: Is there a way to use conditional formatting instead of VBA?

Comment: Possibly. You may get some inspiration [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22350417), but untested.